# Append datestamp to file name after archiving

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line, 7zip

I am using the following code in a batch file:

```
FOR %%i IN (*.bak*) DO 7za a -v1G -r -y -t7z -mx=7 "%%~ni.7za" "%%i"
```

To archive every file in a folder with 7-zip. This code is successfully creating archives with the same file names as the originals (with the 7za extension), but I'd like to also add a datestamp to the file names of the archived files. I know it looks something like this: %YYYYMMDD%

Currently the file being backed up looks like this: CPIB_12345.bak

The archive looks like this: CPIB_12345.7za.001

I want it to look like this: CPIB_12345@20140606.7za.001

Since I can't add comments I'm going to edit this post.

What do I do if, in addition to the above, I have CPIB_12346 and CPIB_13526 and others like that? How do I append the date to all of them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution, that is independent of local time format:

```
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%I in ('wmic os get localdatetime /format:list') do set datetime=%%I
```

and then `%datetime:~0,8%` will give you your `YYYYMMDD`

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
(after yours line of code)
rename "PATH\CPIB_12345.7za.001" "CPIB_12345%date%.7za.001"
pause>null
```

Variable %date% is automaticly replaced by system to doday date. (without time)

And here just a command:

```
rename "path\file" "new file name"
%date%- is replacing word date to current date
```

Comment: `%date%` is region sensitive and contains illegal filename characters, and can also have the day, on different computers.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it assuming UK local date format DD/MM/YYYY

```
set today=%Date%
set year=%today:~-4%
set month=%today:~3,2%
set day=%today:~,2%
set backup_date=%year%%month%%day%

FOR %%i IN (*.bak*) DO 7za a -v1G -r -y -t7z -mx=7 "%%~ni@%backup_date%.7za" "%%i"
```

Would have to adjust positions used when splitting out the date substrings for other date formats.